# How can the machine generate random numbers

Tags: algorithm, random

The Computer is designed to execute  certain tasks exactly.
It is not able to make arbitrary tasks : So how can It generate random numbers?

Comment: This is actually not a practical programming question ..?

Comment: This is a good summary, and is a better reference than a stack-overflow answer: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation

Comment: Please remove the unrelated tags to this question.

Comment: @PaulHankin and the very much related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are right. Computers cannot generate **Purely Random** numbers. Therefore, they are called **Pseudo Random**. Most common technique used, today, to generate a random number is by reading the machine time in milliseconds and perform arithmetic operations on it to get a new number every time. You can read more about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation#Computational_methods)

Comment: It's more to the fact that pRNG sequences are started by a seed. Each pRNG *sequence* will behave as if it generates random numbers, however, it's all based on the seed. Same seed will lead to *exactly* the same sequence. So, the problem is taking a seed that is sufficiently random - it that case is the clock time taken. So, most of the time the clock time is not used for *every* single random number generated - it's used once to set up the sequence.